# How can I migrate from Infor Birst to Power BI?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, migration, visualization, business-intelligence

We have been managing all our data and analytics needs using Infor Birst but we have decided to migrate to Power BI.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no content on the net available regarding this as Birst is such a niche product. Can someone who might have done the same please explain how they have approached the process?

I have tried searching for every resource on the net but cannot find anything.

Comment: the `BIRT` is just reporting tool. You can use `power-bi` as external and make it as primary

Comment: Your question is too broad; there are many different ways to implement these two applications, and your best bet if you have the budget would likely be to hire a consultant who is familiar with both.